# Data Loader Error no viable alternative at character

Tags: query, data-loader, error-messages, data-export

I am receiving the ERROR in Data Loader that says:

> No Viable alternative at character `"`

Does the below query look correct?

```
 Select Bill_To_Contact__c, bill_to_first_name__c, bill_to_last_name__c, Email__c, employee_name__c FROM Sales_Order__c WHERE 
 Contact_Owner__c IN ("005C0000005ke3M","005C0000005iGDX","005C0000006vYCc","005C0000009hI7w","005C0000006yrAs","005C0000005iGEG","005C0000009yWOV") AND 
 employee_name__c IN ("Sales Name1","Sales Name2","Sales Name3","Sales Name4","Sales Name5","Sales Name6","Sales Name7")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are only allowed to use single quotes in your query. Replace all of your double quote characters (`"`) with single quote characters (`'`).